# Arduino Yun and SoftwareSerial Error

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun, software-serial

I am trying to connect an nrf24L01 module to the arduino yun and it prints are gibberish.

this is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 3); // RX, TX
void setup() 
{ 
Serial.begin(9600); 
while (!Serial) { 
;// wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only 
}

Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");
mySerial.begin(115200); 
mySerial.println("Hello, world?");}
void loop() { 
if (mySerial.available()) 
    Serial.write(mySerial.read()); 
if (Serial.available()) 
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

This is the output:

```
Goodnight moon!0'ÚšÚ‚ÚŠ¢Ú:…Ñ•Ý…å�šÑ…ÉÐÕp complete.
```

It should be:

```
0;0;3;9;0 Gateway startup complete.
```

Not sure about the numbers but I'm sure about the text

Answer (score 0):

The speed difference is too much I think. I would increase 
`Serial.begin(9600);` 
 to
`Serial.begin(115200);`
or even better set both values to lower speeds. something like 38400